# Send information from javascript to php file

Tags: php, javascript

I have this function `onEdit()` and now I want to send the value of variable id to a php file (let's call it `test.php`) so that using that value I can auto fill the popup called `modtemplate` which is located in `test.php` file.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

```
function onEdit() {
    var checkboxs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    var id='';
    for (var b=0; b<checkboxs.length; b++) {
        if( (checkboxs[b].type == "checkbox") && (checkboxs[b].checked) )  {
            id = checkboxs[b].value;
                    break;
            }
    }

    if(!id)
        alert("Please select a record to edit");
    else    
        document.getElementById('modtemplate').style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```

Comment: Send an AJAX request? standard form POST? Hard to tell what you are asking

Answer (score 5):

You need some [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use ajax to send the record and then use the response.
or you can pass the value in the url like so

```
if(id) {
     window.location.href = "test.php?id="+id;
}
```

and in the server side u can retrive this value using the $_GET variable

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

For ajax it is a good idea to use [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/ajax) as it takes all the hard work out of the way

Comment: ** It takes all the _learning_ out of the way. Thats all. You should learn how to use AJAX properly, not just skip to a third-party framework.

Comment: @Greg Agnew: learning ajax is absolutely a good idea. But jquery is already there, and it does such a wonderful job. why not use it?